# It crosses two tables with left join with two fields in linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a problem.

I have a query that contains:

```
left join tclientes b on b.codplaza=a.codplaza and b.codcli=a.codcli
```

In the "and" it crosses for second time table A with table B, and I want implements with linq:

```
 var ret = Context.tH
            .GroupJoin(
                    Context.t,
                    tH => tH.cod,
                    t => t.cod,
                    (x, y) => new { tH = x, t = y })
            .Where(R => R.tH.codplaza_usu == placeCode && R.tH.codusuario == codusuario && R.tH.codcli != -1)
            .SelectMany(
                xy => xy.t.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (x, y) => new { tH = x.tH, t = y })
            .Select(s => new TClientesDMO
            {
                codplaza = s.tH.codplaza,
            }).ToList();
```

How can I add second condition of left join?

Comment: [Join by using composite keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/join-by-using-composite-keys)

Comment: I recommend to avoid the fluent syntax at writing such complex queries. It is very hard to read what you want to do. But it's just my subjective opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, the query and the mentioned "double crossing", a possible solution or approach could be:

```
var result = (from th in Context.tH
    join t in Context.t on new {CodPlaza = th.codplaza, CodCli = th.codcli} equals new { CodPlaza = t.codplaza, CodCli = t.codcli }
    where th.codplaza_usu == placeCode 
        && th.codusuario == codusuario 
        && th.codcli != -1
    select new TClientesDMO
    {
        codplaza = th.codplaza,
    }).ToList();
```

This query will return all `codplaza` from `tH` which join with `t` on the properties `codplaza` and `codcli`. Furthermore only `tH` objects will be considerered which have `codplaza_usu == placeCode`, `codusuario == codusuario` and `codcli != -1`.
I hope it matches your needs.

Is it necessary to have the "empty" (`DefaultIfEmpty()`) entries too?
Please give some more information if the query will not fit to your expected result.